# iOS UITableViewController with paging dynamically

Tags: ios, ios6, uitableview, paging

My question is - **How to make** `UITableViewController` **with paging**?

For example, I have send a request which gives me information about the count of science articles. On `UITableViewController` I present all information in `tableView` with static cells, and if I want to see information about another article I should just swipe left or right and then with some animation like transition between controller, I will see same controller with another information.

Basically the main complexity is `UITableViewController`, because if it is `UIVIewController`, I can implement a huge amount of solutions like `iCarousel` and many others, but with `TableViewController` I can't make the same solutions.
I would be happy if you recommend some solution.

Comment: You can implement a normal UIViewController and just implement all the required delegates etc for UITableView and host a tableView within a normal UIViewController

Answer (score 0):

UITableView i think inherits from UIScollView, so you can try saying

```
[tableView setPageEnabled:YES];
```

if that doesn't work, you could try getting the subviews of a table view

```
[tableView subviews];
```

and one of the elements will be a scroll view, but read the documentation to be sure that you are allowed to manipulate the hirearchy of a UITableView

If all else fails, add a gesture control to the tableView and put in vertical gestures and then call the method

```
scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:
```

as well as a left gesture for going back, but then you don't have fluid animation that a scroll view gives.

Props to anyone who has a good valid solution to this.